# Change button color based on response from $http

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can you please suggest me how to change clicked button color based on $http response. Should I use Directives or not. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, you should use directives.

Comment: @Skaparate But before getting the $http response, Directive is getting executed. can you please tell me how to restrict that.

Comment: Does the directive make the request? What's the work flow?

Comment: I am making request from controller which I have written in the directive. Its working now. Is that the correct process I am following??

Comment: you can use directive if you want to change the color of all the buttons rendered by that directive.

Answer (score 2):

just create a scope variable `$scope.buttoncolor` and set it according to your need when getting the `$http` response.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    ...
    ...

    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.buttoncolor = response.data.buttoncolor;
    });
});
```

and in your html, set the color of button using `ng-style`

```
<button ng-style="{'background-color': buttoncolor }">button</button>
```

---

**EDIT**

I've created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gYXih5o4L9Zz7J7T3NDm?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('parentCtrl1', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.makeRequest = function(event) {
        var d = angular.toJson(model);
        return $http.get('file.json');
    };
}).controller('parentCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.makeRequest = function(event) {
        return $http.get('/not/an/api/call');
    };
}).directive('colorBtn', function($log) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        link: onLink,
        template: '<button ng-click="request($event)">Request</button>',
        scope: {
            onClick: '&clickcb'
        }
    }

    function onLink(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.request = function($e) {
            el.removeClass('error').removeClass('success');
            if (scope.onClick !== undefined) {
                scope.onClick({
                        event: $e
                    })
                    .then(success, error);
            }
        };

        function success(response) {
            el.addClass('success');
        }

        function error(response) {
            el.addClass('error');
        }
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<div class="parent-1" ng-controller="parentCtrl1">
    <color-btn clickcb="makeRequest(event)"></color-btn>
</div>

<div class="parent-2" ng-controller="parentCtrl2">
    <color-btn clickcb="makeRequest(event)"></color-btn>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .error { background-color: red; color: white; }
  .success { background-color: green; color: white; }
</style>
```

Working plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/mvpKeGBvdKKnil3QeWuf/